shadowmap edge jitter
I'm trying to implement shadowmap, first I crop the viewcone based on the current camera's viewcone and a set shadow distance, use the resulting eight points to determine a bounding sphere to build the matrix, when I move the camera, the edges of the shadowmap get jittery, I've checked some information and it mentions that I need to pair the virtual camera's world coordinates to it to the shadowmap pixels. After that I made the following attempt:
Vector3f light_dir = _light._light_dir.xyz;
light_dir = Normalize(light_dir);
f32 radius_align_down = acosf(DotProduct(light_dir, -Vector3f::kUp));
f32 angle_align_down = radius_align_down * k2Angle;
f32 project_xz_length = world_unit_per_pixel / sinf((90.0f - angle_align_down) * k2Radius);
Vector3f project_xz_dir = light_dir;
project_xz_dir.y = 0.0f;
project_xz_dir = Normalize(project_xz_dir);
f32 dot_forward = abs(DotProduct(project_xz_dir, Vector3f::kForward));

Vector3f project_dis = Vector3f::kOne;
Vector3f right = Normalize(CrossProduct(Vector3f::kUp, light_dir));
Vector3f up = Normalize(CrossProduct(light_dir, right));
Vector3f light_pos = _light._light_pos.xyz;
//find four point on virtual camera's near plane(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1),and then
//project them to xz plane,calculate the aabb
Vector3f p0 = light_pos;
Vector3f p1 = light_pos + right * world_unit_per_pixel;
Vector3f p2 = light_pos + up * world_unit_per_pixel;
Vector3f p3 = light_pos + (right + up) * world_unit_per_pixel;
Vector3f world_p[4];
FindIntersectionWithZXPlane(p0, light_dir, world_p[0]);
FindIntersectionWithZXPlane(p1, light_dir, world_p[1]);
FindIntersectionWithZXPlane(p2, light_dir, world_p[2]);
FindIntersectionWithZXPlane(p3, light_dir, world_p[3]);

Vector3f p_min = world_p[0], p_max = world_p[0];
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
{
    p_min.x = std::min<float>(p_min.x, world_p[i].x);
    p_min.y = std::min<float>(p_min.y, world_p[i].y);
    p_min.z = std::min<float>(p_min.z, world_p[i].z);
    p_max.x = std::max<float>(p_max.x, world_p[i].x);
    p_max.y = std::max<float>(p_max.y, world_p[i].y);
    p_max.z = std::max<float>(p_max.z, world_p[i].z);
}
project_dis.x = p_max.x - p_min.x;
project_dis.z = p_max.z - p_min.z;
project_dis.y = project_xz_length / tanf(radius_align_down);
shadow_cam_pos /= project_dis;
shadow_cam_pos.x = floor(shadow_cam_pos.x);
shadow_cam_pos.y = floor(shadow_cam_pos.y);
shadow_cam_pos.z = floor(shadow_cam_pos.z);
shadow_cam_pos *= project_dis;

This way works with no rotation of the light on the y-axis, otherwise it has no effect, I don't understand why？I've drawn a simple schematic where the rectangles represent the shadowmap veins projected onto the zx plane.


Did you multiply the texture coordinates with the texture matrix? Or even with its inverse that is. But I am not sure, might be that T is part of the projection matrix already.
